# How to disable transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616 message

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

While subscribing message using `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` in spring and camel using failover activemq transport I am continuously getting below INFO messages.

```
2016-08-25 15:00:07,235 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
2016-08-25 15:00:08,265 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
2016-08-25 15:00:08,265 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
2016-08-25 15:00:09,296 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
2016-08-25 15:00:09,328 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
2016-08-25 15:00:10,299 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
2016-08-25 15:00:10,346 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
2016-08-25 15:00:11,318 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  transport.failover.FailoverTransport Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
```

Is this possible to disable this INFO message on console or is there any time interval for printing this message on console?

I have tried to use some ActiveMQ transport connection option but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing which comes to my mind that you could play around with the failover parameters like documented here: http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

Comment: :Thanks for the reply. I figure it out in a way where I am disabling Info at log4j level of activemq like this : logging.level.org.apache.activemq=WARN

Answer (score 0):

We found that the connection pool is disabled by default when using SpringBoot and ActiveMQ.  We set the following property in our `application.yml` file to enable the pool:

```
spring.activemq.pool.enabled: true
```

Setting the log level to `WARN` just masks the problem, as it will still be discarding and recreating the connections behind the scenes.

Comment: We have `spring.activemq.pool.enabled=true` in our props, but we keep getting those messages with `broker-url` set to `failover://(tcp://...,tcp://...)?randomize=false&initialReconnectDelay=5000&maxReconnectAttempts=4&timeout=3000&maxReconnectDelay=30000&jms.prefetchPolicy.all=10`.
So it's probably somewhere in those parameters. I agree that just pushing the log level is not real solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the ActiveMQ Forum:

> The default idleTimeout of the PooledConnectionFactory is only 30 
>   seconds. And physical connections are borrowed in a round-robin fashion. 
>   So if it takes the application more than 30 seconds to cycle through the 5 
>   connections, you'll start observing connection churn, which seems exactly 
>   what's happening in your case. 
>   Is it possible that 30 secs elapsed between subsequent uses of the 
>   JmsTemplate in your scenario?

So the solution should be to update the connection pool's idleTimeout.